# Making menu items visible/invisible according to user role

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I use a  PHP Script (AdLinkFly - Monetized URL Shortener)

I want to display different menu according to login user . If user is client then display Manage Account and LogOut otherwise show Sing-Up and Sing-In.

Here is the home page http://adshort.ga
Here is the code "front.ctp" :

```html
<html lang="<?= locale_get_primary_language(null) ?>">
<head>
    <?= $this->element('front_head'); ?>
</head>
<body class="<?= ($this->request->here == $this->request->webroot) ? 'home' : 'inner-page' ?>">
<?= get_option('after_body_tag_code'); ?>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only"><?= __('Toggle navigation') ?></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <?php
            $logo = get_logo();
            $class = '';
            if ($logo['type'] == 'image') {
                $class = 'logo-image';
            }
            ?>
            <a class="navbar-brand <?= $class ?>" href="<?= $this->Url->build('/'); ?>"><?= $logo['content'] ?></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                
                <li>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/'); ?>"><?= __('Home') ?></a>
                </li>
                
                
                <?php if (get_option('enable_advertising', 'yes') == 'yes') : ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/advertising-rates'); ?>"><?= __('Advertising') ?></a>
                    </li>
                    
                    
                <?php endif; ?>
                
                
                <li>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/payout-rates'); ?>"><?= __('Payout Rates') ?></a>
                </li>
                
                
                <?php if ((bool)get_option('blog_enable', false)) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/blog'); ?>"><?= __('Blog') ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                
                <li>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/auth/signin'); ?>"><?= __('Sign in') ?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/auth/signUP'); ?>"><?= __('Sign Up') ?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build('/member/dashboard'); ?>"><?= __('Dashboard') ?></a>
                </li>
               
            
                <?php if (count(get_site_languages(true)) > 1) : ?>
                    <li class="dropdown language-selector">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-language"></i> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <?php foreach (get_site_languages(true) as $lang) : ?>
                                <li>
                                    <?= $this->Html->link(
                                        locale_get_display_name($lang, $lang),
                                        '/' . $this->request->url . '?lang=' . $lang
                                    ); ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?= $this->fetch('content') ?>

<?= $this->element('front_footer'); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Im not expert in PHP i would be grateful if someone could help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [website with different content for each type of user (about security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245969/website-with-different-content-for-each-type-of-user-about-security)

Comment: This looks horrible, looks like someone tried to work with CakePHP like it is this abomination of software development called Wordpress :s Honestly, ditch that code and finde somebody who knows how to work with CakePHP and honors best practice from this decade to rewrite this.

Answer (score -1):

When the user log in, start a [session](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) `session_start()`, then add to a `$_SESSION` variable when you store a value that the script can recognise, for example: `$_SESSION['userLogged'] = true;`, then at the main file, you can add this:

```
      session_start();
      if($_SESSION['userLogged'] == true) {
         //Display here the HTML with echo function
      } else {
         //Load the normal page
      }
```

Imagine you want to display a `<p>` tag with the text "Hello world!", then you would have to go to the html file, find the tag where you want the code to be executed, and then do the code below. For example:

```
    if($_SESSION['userLogged'] == true) {
       echo '<p>Hello world!</p>'; 
    }
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your fast replay.
I'm not expert with this can you explain more for me pleas if that possible?

Comment: I've edited the answer, let me know if do you understand it now @AchrafYo